# Retrieve specific version of document using Alfresco REST API

Tags: api, rest, alfresco

I'm using Alfresco Community 5.0b, but when I try to get the list of versions, using
`GET /alfresco/service/api/node/{store_type}/{store_id}/{id}/versions`,
I simply get an HTTP 404 error.  According to https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Repository_RESTful_API_Reference#Retrieve_all_versions_.28getAllVersions.29, this is the recommended way to get the list of versions.

the Content and MetaData queries both work fine when I try 
`GET /alfresco/service/api/node/{store_type}/{store_id}/{id}/content` and 
`GET /alfresco/service/api/node/{store_type}/{store_id}/{id}/metadata`.  What am I missing?

Comment: Did you see the big warning at the top of that page? Also, why are you not using CMIS to do this?

Comment: I'm not using CMIS because it is approximately 2x slower in every case that I've load tested so far compared to the REST API, even when using the succinct=true parameter.  Both are supported.  Why should it matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a try to this,

```
/alfresco/service/api/version?nodeRef={noderef}
```

Comment: Hallelujah!  Thanks for the help.  I've grown to really dislike the Alfresco documentation since everything is documented, but not completely enough to actually use it.  Thanks!!!